# Dont want to press Ctrl +D to end a file. Any alternative

Tags: linux, shell

I want a linux cmd to write the value of a variable into a file. Heres what i have,

```
x=$(cat /home/kate/Documents/Desktop/New-ACE-Deploy/deploy/ace/deploysetup/ConfFiles/online_ace_stable-m4.5.conf)
echo $x
cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
cat > online_ace_stable-m4.5.conf
echo "$x" >> "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/online_ace_stable-m4.5.conf"
```

But i have to press Ctrl +D to end. I dont want to do it. Any alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `cat > online_ace_stable-m4.5.conf` line and you should be fine with regards to pressing Ctrl+D. If the file may exist before you run the script, you want to additionally replace `>>` (appending) on the last line with `>` (overwriting).

If you really need to explicitly make sure the file exists and is empty, use `echo -n > online_ace_stable-m4.5.conf`.

Comment: It will be created when you append to it using `>>` as well, you don't need to create it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Your [`cat` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cat) on the 4th line is incorrect. It is missing a file parameter. Without this parameter is copies `stdin` to `stdout`. This goes on until `stdin` is closed, hence you need to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>

In order to fix your problem, change the line it to:

```
cat online_ace_stable-m4.5.conf
```

(Note the `>` is gone)

If you want to create an empty (new) file, use [`touch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/touch) instead of `cat`:

```
touch online_ace_stable-m4.5.conf
```

or directly echo to the file:

```
echo "$x" > "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/online_ace_stable-m4.5.conf"
```

as it it not require to first create it and make sure that old contents are not kept. (Note the single `>` instead of the double `>>`)

Comment: I did note the > is gone. But it appears that line itself is not needed to create a file. Thanks for the additional infm of 'touch' cmd.